# Unable to return string forms of DateField and TimeField field values

Tags: python, django

I have a `models.DateField` and `models.TimeField` fields in my model class. I want to return the values of the date field as a string from the `__unicode__` method. As I do this, I get an error saying `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.date' and 'str'`. The following is my model class code:

```
class Appointment(models.Model):
    apDate = models.DateField()
    apTime = models.TimeField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.apDate.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

The following is the full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 430, in __str__
    return force_text(self).encode('utf-8')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\encoding.py", line 100, in force_text
    s = s.__unicode__()
  File "C:\RAKESH\djangowork\mysite\books\models.py", line 52, in __unicode__
    return self.apDate.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.date' and 'str'
```

Please help me solve this problem. How do I return the date string correctly?

Thanks,
Rakesh.

Comment: the error doesn't make sense to me unless... you are in Python console, you previously had different code in your `__unicode__` method (which did something like `return self.apDate + "something"`) and you haven't restarted the console after updating the code... the traceback then shows the source of line #52 _as it currently is on disk_ even though the console is actually running the older version of the code _as it was when imported_

Comment: Thanks @Anentropic for pointing it out. Looks like the console session still remembered the concatenation operation.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, looks like the console session still remembered the previous code even though the actual code has been changed. I just had to restart the shell again to see the changes.